# How to check canvas has loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I'm using the [`react-globe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-globe) package to render a globe with markers, and need to setup a loading screen to show while the globe texture loads. How can I either check that the canvas has been fully painted to or that the globe is ready and then hide a loading screen?

Is there a way to check the HTML5 Canvas element is finished loading?

This is my current setup: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-globe-interactive-forked-98tyz?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: [documentation](https://react-globe.netlify.app/props) has an `onGlobeTextureLoaded`, that's likely a good place to start.

Comment: [unoptomised example solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-globe-interactive-forked-qvw4v?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: @CallumMorrisson - I tried something similar, but had the logic slightly off. This worked. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark is as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ReactGlobe component has different props to help the globe behave in a certain way. One of them is onGlobeTextureLoaded, which is a callback for handling the completion of the globe texture load.

```js
<ReactGlobe
    height="100vh"
    markers={markers}
    options={options}
    width="100vw"
    initialCoordinates={initialCoordinates}
    onClickMarker={onClickMarker}
    onDefocus={onDefocus}
    onGlobeTextureLoaded={() => console.log('Globe Texture Loaded')}/*or the name of a function used for handling this*/
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The react globe has component has dffrent categories to help the globe behave in a certain Way. One of them is on the globe texture loaded which is  pront for handling the compliction of the globe texture load,

Comment: A near exact copy of a prior answer.